# How to connect to a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: linux, database, sql, postgresql, database-administration

I have a website written in Python / Django, and it is functioning well on a CentOS server (I wasn't one who set it up though). Now I want to set this website up locally on my Mac OS X or Linux system to continue developing the website. Yet the website won't launch locally without connecting to a PostgreSQL database. This means that I need to download the database from the server. To download the database I need to know its location.

`# ps auxw |  grep postgres | grep -- -D` gives the location as

`/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/`

But where exactly is the database in this directory? Here is the directory listing:

```
drwx------ 10 postgres postgres 4096 Апр 19  2018 base
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Май  4 06:11 global
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Май  3 18:36 pg_clog
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Окт 19  2017 pg_commit_ts
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Окт 19  2017 pg_dynshmem
drwx------  4 postgres postgres 4096 Окт 19  2017 pg_logical
drwx------  4 postgres postgres 4096 Окт 19  2017 pg_multixact
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Май  3 14:45 pg_notify
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Окт 19  2017 pg_replslot
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Окт 19  2017 pg_serial
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Окт 19  2017 pg_snapshots
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Май  3 14:45 pg_stat
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Окт 19  2017 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Май  3 18:36 pg_subtrans
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Окт 19  2017 pg_tblspc
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Окт 19  2017 pg_twophase
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres    4 Окт 19  2017 PG_VERSION
drwx------  3 postgres postgres 4096 Май  3 19:11 pg_xlog
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres   88 Окт 19  2017 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  133 Май  3 14:45 postmaster.opts
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  100 Май  3 14:45 postmaster.pid
```

This is the listing of the directory `base`:

```
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Май  4 06:11 1
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Окт 19  2017 12995
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres  4096 Май  3 14:45 12996
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 20480 Май  3 14:46 16387
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 12288 Май  4 06:11 16388
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 12288 Май  4 06:11 16389
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 20480 Май  3 14:46 18859
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 20480 Май  3 14:46 26185
```

Does anyone know how this relates to a Postgre database? Where exactly is it located?

If one wants to connect to a database using psql, it is necessary to know the name of the database. But how?
Would appreciate some help.

Comment: The database is in `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main`, but I guess you don't want to "download" it, but instead want a "dump" of the database. There are command line tools `pg_dump` and `pg_dumpall` for that. But for `pg_dump` you need to know the database name (and user and password). For starters, try `psql -c '\l'` to find out the name of your database. It's possible that you have to change to user `postgres` for that to login without password.

Comment: @Freddy Thanks. But how can I then install this dump locally? Locally I actually have MariaDB.

Comment: I guess a postgresql dump won't work with MariaDB without heavy modification. You should setup a postgresql installation on your Mac, preferably in the same version or use a virtualized Linux server for development.

Comment: @Freddy But if /etc/postgresql/9.6/main is actually where the database is located, why should one make a dump of the database rather than copying the files to the same location of a virtualized linux server, say? How can one make use of the dump in this manner?

Comment: Because it's easier to handle and you could keep several versions of your database for development and testing like a version with "live data", one for "development" (with different tables) etc. To create and restore a dump only takes a few seconds and it's just one file. (1) [Backup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-pgdump.html#PG-DUMP-EXAMPLES): `pgdump dbname > dbname_dump.sql` (2) [Restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE): `psql dbname < dbname_dump.sql`